# A Line distrupting in front of my Donut model

Tags: modeling, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, edit-mode, subdivision-surface

**I was making my Donut... and when i have done it's icing(the creamy layering of a Donut) a line is coming in btw..

I am not able to find a way to fix it in edit mode**
**It is looking like this:**
[image]

*As some people would have guessed that i have made it from the tutorial of blenderguru*... **so if any person already made it(through the tutorial or not)  please to help me to make me my blender project...**

Answer (score 1):

I've made the donut before! This problem was mentioned in the videos somewhere, either in the same episode or the follow up episode. It is caused by an extra accidental layer of icing when extruding the region by extruding twice, the layer is probably meshed with your icing, so at this point the only thing you can do is delete the icing, and make a new one :D.